# PhpStorm Debugger never enters code, but page doesn't finish loading while debugger is running

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

I am using PhpStorm on Ubuntu which I'm running on a Hyper-V machine.  I'm trying to configure the PhpStorm debugger with XDebug.  I've set a breakpoint in my code, but when I click "Start Listening for PHP Debug Connections" in PhpStorm and refresh my page, the debugger never enters my code.  The debugger must be doing *something* because the page in the browser stays loading, until I click Stop in PhpStorm.  If I don't click for the debugger to listen for connections, the page loads correctly.

The Debug window shows the error `Remote file path '/var/www/magento2/pub/index.php' is not mapped to any file path in project`, but I don't know how to get that to map correctly.  In the path mappings windows, under "Include path", it shows a bunch of paths, but the path `/var/www/magento2/pub` isn't there.  I can't find anywhere to add an additional path.  Could this be a permissions issue for that folder?  What permissions do I need to allow PhpStorm to map that path?

If I uncheck "use path mapping" in `Preferences > Language & Framework > PHP > Servers` and leave "Break at first line in PHP scripts" checked, then the debugger breaks on the first line of code, but I don't want to break until my breakpoint is hit.

If I uncheck "use path mapping" and don't check "Break at first line in PHP scripts", then I get the error `Debug session was finished without being paused. It may be caused by path mappings misconfiguration or not synchronized local and remote projects.  To figure out the problem check path mappings configuration for 'mydomain.local' server at PHP|Servers or enable Break at first line in PHP scripts option (from Run menu).`

Here's my XDebug configuration

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so

xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_children=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_data=-1
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
```

**Update:**

Here are the responses to @LazyOne's questions

1) The path to the project root is /var/www/magento2

2) [image]

One thing here which I think may be related to the problem is that under `Include Path`, the `/var/www/magento/pub` directory is not shown.  That's what PhpStorm is referencing on that first error I described above.  It's like PhpStorm found some of my directories with PHP files, but not all of them.

3) [Here is the XDebug log](https://pastebin.com/eff1RQwd)

**Update 2:**

Here is what my project looks like

[image]

Here is my Directories window

[image]

I'm assuming that the reason that all the `vendor/...` directories are under Excluded Folders is that they are in `.gitignore`.  Some of the code that I'm setting a breakpoint in is in a subdirectory of one of the `vendor` directories and some of the code is in a subdirectory of `app/code/` (which is under Source Folders)

I added `/var/www/magento2/pub` to the `Include Path` under `Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP`.  That eliminated the error about `/var/www/magento2/pub/index.php`.  Now it's partially working.  If I have PhpStorm break on the first line of PHP scripts, the debugger does start as soon as I refresh my page.  However, after I step over the first line of code, I get the error `PHP CS Fixer: Can not correctly run the tool with parameters...` and then the debugger seems to stop working.

If I don't select `Break at first line in PHP Scripts`, and I put a breakpoint further into my code, I still get the same "debug session was finished without being paused" error.

I'm not sure what PHP CS Fixer is, nor do I want it to run.  Is there a way to disable that?

Comment: 1) Where you project is located (the path etc) 2) What is you path mapping is? 3) Enable and collect Xdebug log -- it will tell what file it tries to debug etc.

Comment: @LazyOne I updated my post with answers to your questions.

Comment: 1) If it's a local project and no symlinks used anywhere in the path then you do not need the path mappings. 2) I see more than 1 debug session there (you should have limited it to just 1 session). In 1st session it tries to debug `/var/www/magento2/pub/index.php`, in 2nd it's `/var/www/magento2/pub/static.php`; in 3rd it's `/var/www/magento2/pub/get.php` (and it's run in parallel to 2nd request). And then there are even more sessions....

Comment: 1) Can you please show how the project looks in Project View panel -- need to see what folders are there. In particular then `pub` folder (as it's missing as per your words). 2) Please also show a screenshot of `Settings/Preferences | Directories` -- in particular folders that are marked as Excluded (ignore composer packages from `vendor` folder). If `pub` folder is excluded then IDE cannot stop there and "Remote file path '/var/www/magento2/pub/index.php' is not mapped to any file path in project" makes sense... Need more info about project setup. Right now it looks like misconfig on IDE side

Comment: P.S. As I understand you may have edited the log / screenshot to hide the company name / website domain ? Or it's actually served from `mydomain.local` address?

Comment: @LazyOne Yes, I edited it to hide the company/domain.  I'll work on getting those other things.

Comment: Regarding the multiple sessions, I think that's due to how Magento works.  I think it's using JS to call several requests simultaneously.  I'm only refreshing the page one time.

Comment: Yes, multiple sessions must be due to that as I saw JPG image (magento logo) -- could be an image used as favicon; there was also some JSON output (AJAX request I guess)...

Comment: 1) Your `pub` folder seems to be fine (not excluded, based on your screenshots). The fact that you had to add it via "Inlcude Paths"  suggests that it's auto-excluded by JavaScript plugin (or some other JS-related plugin). Can that folder be named as `public` for example? That should help  with that issue.

Comment: No, unfortunately I can't change the names of the folders.  Magento requires certain paths.

Comment: 2) *"I get the error PHP CS Fixer: Can not correctly run the tool with parameters... and then the debugger seems to stop working."* 1. Please check how many simultaneous debug sessions you can have in IDE (`Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Debug | Max simultaneous connections` -- make sure it's more than 1 (e.g. `3`). 2. Debug for PHP CS Fixer might get triggered by `xdebug.remote_autostart=1` , better set it to be `=0` and invoke debug session via cookie (every Xdebug browser extension uses that).

Comment: 3) Try removing all breakpoints and place one in `pub/index.php` -- can you debug that file? If you create some test file next to index.php (e.g. test.php) with the following content: `<?php $a = 1; $b=2; $c = $a + $b; echo $c;` -- each statement on separate line -- can you debug it? If you can make simple script debugging first, then it will mean that Xdebug & IDE are configured correctly and you can then start digging deeper into the actual Magento code debug.

Comment: 4) What's your IDE version BTW? I hope it's 2019.1 or newer. 5) Try getting rid of red entries on your Directories screen (that denotes missing folder) -- maybe they affect this somehow... TBH -- no other ideas right now. I guess If I would be sitting in front of that project myself I could spot something, but right now, only using this limited info -- no better ideas come into my mind right now..

Comment: My only other idea right now -- close IDE, go to project root and back up & delete `.idea` folder, then open IDE and use Open to open that project folder again  -- it will create a new project in IDE from scratch using those files. Maybe there is some broken stuff in existing config ...

Comment: 1) Yes, I can debug that simple `test.php` that you suggested.  2) I'm on PhpStorm 2019.3  3) Now I have an error "cannot find a local copy of the file on server /var/www/magento2/pub/get.php; Local path is /var/www/magento2/get.php.  It seems suspicious that those two paths to `get.php` are different.  Do you think that's a symptom of a path problem, and if you so do you know how I'd fix it?  By the way, thank you for helping me with this.  You've taken a lot of your time to assist me.

Comment: "cannot find a local copy of the file on server" Check the path mappings again -- if needed, provide mapping for `pub` folder (could be under "Include Path" node since you have said that you added it there). Accordingly to your Xdebug file it always reported as `/var/www/magento2/pub/get.php`. If your test.php file is in the same folder, and you did the same debug via browser as the actual Magento website, it should just work ... cos I do not know how it can work for `pub/test.php` but fails with "cannot locate file" for `pub/get.php` ...